# SWT TabFolder lazy loading

Tags: java, swt

I have two browsers controls one in each tab.  I notice that the browser doesn't seem to load until I click on the tab.

I think there is some lazy loading going on here.

How can I make the browser load its contents right away before the user clicks on the tab?

Answer (score 0):

The SWT browser uses instance of a browser of the platform on which it's running. And it can be underlying browser-specific behavior to not load until window became visible.

To check this you can addProgressListener and LocationListener and see when the actual load is actually starting to go.

You can try such things like programmatically making window active for 1 millisecond.